# Facing error in Python Olymptrade API unable to solve

Tags: python, pip, python-module

```
from olymptradeapi.stable_api import Olymptrade 
account=Olymptrade("email","password",set_ssid="1000869312323232143243243243234432")
_,r=account.connect()
```

When I try to `pip install olymptradeapi.stable_api` this library getting no module found or no package found.

I have also tried    `olymptradeapi.api` and `olymptradeapi`  but facing same issue. Can you please help?

Comment: What is OympTrade? It doesn't seem to be recognised by PyPi. Do you need to download it manually from somewhere?

Comment: The first link in Internet search for "olymptradeapi". The project seems to be non pip-installable.